# Parse JSON with duplicate keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, twitter

I am working with the Twitter API for trends (see: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/trends/trends-for-location/api-reference/get-trends-place).

The API returns the following JSON:

```
{
  trends: [
    {
      name: 'Boris',
      url: 'http://twitter.com/search?q=Boris',
      promoted_content: null,
      query: 'Boris',
      tweet_volume: 1083274
    },
    {
      name: '#COVID19',
      url: 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23COVID19',
      promoted_content: null,
      query: '%23COVID19',
      tweet_volume: 2088454
    },
    {
      name: '#WorldHealthDay',
      url: 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23WorldHealthDay',
      promoted_content: null,
      query: '%23WorldHealthDay',
      tweet_volume: 250817
    }
  ],
  as_of: '2020-04-07T14:06:49Z',
  created_at: '2020-04-07T14:03:32Z',
  locations: [ { name: 'London', woeid: 44418 } ]
}
```

I would like to transform this into a Javascript array containing all of the values where the key is name; ie.:

```
arr=["Boris", "#COVID19", "WorldHealthDay"]
```

How can I achieve this?  From what I have read, native JavaScript JSON parsers cannot handle duplicate keys.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: `arr = data.trends.map(t => t.name)` -> `["Boris", "#COVID19", "#WorldHealthDay"]`

Answer (score 2):

your data:

```
trends = [
    {
      name: 'Boris',
      url: 'http://twitter.com/search?q=Boris',
      promoted_content: null,
      query: 'Boris',
      tweet_volume: 1083274
    },
    {
      name: '#COVID19',
      url: 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23COVID19',
      promoted_content: null,
      query: '%23COVID19',
      tweet_volume: 2088454
    },
    {
      name: '#WorldHealthDay',
      url: 'http://twitter.com/search?q=%23WorldHealthDay',
      promoted_content: null,
      query: '%23WorldHealthDay',
      tweet_volume: 250817
    }
  ];
```

then use map

```
var ans = trends.map(d => d.name)
```

results:

```
 ans = ["Boris", "#COVID19", "#WorldHealthDay"]
```

Comment: ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you.  Spot on.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays can contain duplicate VALUES, which is what you've requested. Arrays do not contain keys, and these strings in the array are also values of the 'name' key inside of the JSON returned from the twitter API.

To solve your problem, for example, with a very basic iteration and no Array.map

```
const data = JSON.parse(data_str);
const arr = [];
for (const trend of data.trends) {
    arr.push(trend.name);
}
```

Comment: how it is different from `[].map `??

Comment: It isn't, but it may help this person understand more clearly how exactly the process works.

Comment: Yes, I know that arrays do not contain keys - I was trying to explain which data I wanted to get out of the JSON.  Thank you for trying to make it simple for me - but I cannot get your code to work, so I am going to get the mark the previous answer as the answer.  BTW - your fancy new push() method completely threw me - that wasn't there back in 2001 when I actually wrote code for a living!

Comment: @NealO'Kelly Array.prototype.push was actually around in IE 5.5, back in 2000 :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push. The for-of loop is ES6, so if you're running it in an old browser I suppose it might not work.